# TrustFailure Error Thrown When Using AWS Powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use AWS powershell to update metadata for items in my S3 bucket. I am using the script:

```
Set-AWSCredentials -ProfileName S3Test ;
write-S3Object -BucketName myS3bucket `
               -Key Folder/Subfolder/Myfile.txt `
               -Content "Myfile.txt `
               -Metadata @{"x-amz-meta-custommetadata" = "TESTMEtadata"} `
               -Headers @{"Content-Type" = "binary/octet-stream"} ;
```

I am able to run this script successfully from my own account on my computer but when I try to automate this script using a service account I am getting the error message:

```
write-S3Object : A WebException with status TrustFailure was thrown.
At line:1 char:1
+ write-S3Object -BucketName myS3Bucket `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: 
(Amazon.PowerShe...eS3ObjectCmdlet:WriteS3ObjectCmdlet) [Write-S3Obje
   t], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 

Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.WriteS3ObjectCmdlet
```

From what I have found on similar issues I tried to add this line to my script:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true} ;
```

However this results in a different error message:

```
write-S3Object : A WebException with status RecieveFailure was thrown.
At line:1 char:1
+ write-S3Object -BucketName myS3Bucket `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: 
(Amazon.PowerShe...eS3ObjectCmdlet:WriteS3ObjectCmdlet) [Write-S3Obje
   t], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 

Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.WriteS3ObjectCmdlet
```

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing these problems and how I would be able to resolve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems liken a callback is run using what is defined in:

`[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}`

I'm not exactly sure what triggers it based off of what I read but the callback seems to be set on service accounts.

Try setting it to:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = $null
```

Reference:

https://forrestbrazeal.com/2015/06/15/adventures-in-aws-the-worlds-scariest-stack-trace/

Comment: Unfortunately when I add this line to my script the first error that was generated begins again: write-S3Object : A WebException with status TrustFailure was thrown.
At line:1 char:1
+ write-S3Object -BucketName myS3Bucket `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: 
(Amazon.PowerShe...eS3ObjectCmdlet:WriteS3ObjectCmdlet) [Write-S3Obje
   t], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 

Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.WriteS3ObjectCmdlet

Comment: Are you running this with the service account on another machine besides your own?

Comment: My thought is (and from what I'm seeing it seems correct) that "Trust Failure" indicates that the AWS SSL/TLS cert issuers root certificate is not in the root cert store of the machine you are running the script with the service account on. Check and see if you have a "Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority" in your trusted root store on the failing machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your date on the server.

I had the same error accessing AWS endpoints, but the solution was a touch simpler... I was testing a process where I set the date on the server back a couple of months, which caused the AWS connection process to throw the request out.